# Can't update child entities in my controller with entity framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Having these two entities, I fetch them, map them to viwemodels/dtos before I pass them to the UI.
I also had to ignore reference loop handling, in my startup.cs file, to map them to DTO's correctly.

```
public class Matter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MatterExposure> Exposures { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
public class MatterExposure
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public Matter Matter { get; set; }
     // other properties
}
```

When I save the form (which includes a table of 'MatterExposure's) in the UI I pass everything back to the controller to be saved. **INFO** - not saving child entities 'MatterExposure' yet in below controller call and it works fine!

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateData(string id, MatterForClaimDetailedDto generalMatterDto)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    var matter = await _autoRepo.GetMatter(id);
    // fill some matter data and add a child then save and it works fine 
    if (await _autoRepo.SaveAll())
            return NoContent(); 
}
public class MatterForClaimDetailedDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public GeneralMatterDto MatterData { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MatterExposure> Exposures { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

Now I want to add the update of MatterExposure entities, as I could have made changes to them in the UI. So I try to use UpdateRange like this

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateData(string id, MatterForClaimDetailedDto generalMatterDto)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    var matter = await _autoRepo.GetMatter(id);
    matter.EditedDate = DateTime.Now;
    matter.FirstName = generalMatterDto.FirstName;
    matter.LastName = generalMatterDto.LastName;

    _autoRepo.UpdateRange<List<MatterExposure>>(generalMatterDto.Exposures.ToList());
    await _autoRepo.SaveAll()
}
public void UpdateRange<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    _autoContext.UpdateRange(entity);
}
```

But on calling UpdateRange I get this exception message:

> "The entity type 'List MatterExposure' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model."

In my context I have this:

```
public DbSet<MatterExposure> MatterExposure { get; set; }
```

I then tried below with no luck

```
public DbSet<List<MatterExposure>> MatterExposure { get; set; }
```

I thought I would try updating each individual 'MatterExposure' entity to see if that would change anything. So I tried removing the UpdateRange call and tried with individual 'MatterExposure' entities

```
  foreach(var exposure in generalMatterDto.Exposures) {
      _autoRepo.Update<MatterExposure>(exposure);
   }
   // in my repo I have this with different things I tried
   public void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        // _autoContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        //_autoContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
        _autoContext.Update(entity);
       // _autoContext.ChangeTracker.
    }
```

On the first loop through each 'MatterExposure' Update call to the repo I get this exception

> "The instance of entity type 'MatterExposure' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."

After the exception above I tried I put the loop at the top of the controller method to see if the other entity stuff was interfering.

```
// at top of controler method before the other entity actions are performed
foreach(var exposure in generalMatterDto.Exposures) {
    _autoRepo.Update<MatterExposure>(exposure);
}
```

And moving the for loop to the top of the controller, runs through the 1st iteration but then fails on the second giving me the same error message again

> "The instance of entity type 'MatterExposure' cannot be tracked because 
>   another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. 
>   When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. 
>   Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."

**QUESTION** - am I not updating the child entities correctly or is it something else?

Comment: DbSet.Update is only necessary , if you haven't loaded your entities before, from the same context. Is this the case ? I can't see any "SaveChanges" call, is this hidden in your SaveAll ?

Comment: Have you tried writing "_autoRepo.UpdateRange<MatterExposure>(generalMatterDto.Exposures);" ?

Comment: I think the problem ist that you are using the Collection of Matters in both the Entity Object and the DTO. Maybe you should also map them to a MatterDto.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Do you mean a MatterExposureDto? Your referring to using my entity to pass back and forth between my UI instead of a Dto for 'MatterExposure's?